# Is it possible to make elements fill width or height in Grid in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Grid with rectangles like this:

```
Grid {
        columns: 3
        spacing: 2
        Rectangle { color: "red"; width: 80; height: 100 }
        Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 40; height: 100 }
        Rectangle { color: "blue"; width: 100; height: 40 }
        Rectangle { color: "cyan"; width: 100; height: 50 }
        Rectangle { color: "magenta"; width: 20; height: 20 }
        Rectangle { color: "cyan"; width: 100; height: 50 }
        Rectangle { color: "magenta"; width: 20; height: 20 }
    }
```

It does exactly what it's supposed to do, places all elements in a Grid formation. But is it possible to make the elements fill the empty space between them? Mind that I'm not looking for a GridLayout, bacause I need the elements to be of a different size, not the fixed cellSize that layouts offer. I'm planning on implementing a mouse drag resize, so it should act like a Splitter between two Grid elements. Any ideas on how to implement this? Is it even possible to resize elements inside a Grid independetly?
Edit: this is what it should look like
[image]

Comment: I think you should provide an image that demonstrates what you need as the result.

Comment: @SMR provided an example, I think it's called a flexible layout

Comment: At present, I can offer three potential solutions: 1) Using [GridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html) and [columnSpan](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#columnSpan-attached-prop), 2) Using the [Flow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-flow.html) component, and 3) Incorporating [Row](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-row.html) components within a [Column](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-column.html) component. If not, you need to impalement your own custom container.

Comment: @SMR You see, the problem with using the column and row layouts is that I need to resize the elements both by height and width. The Flow component looks very promising, I'll look into it and see if it works for my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip about Layouts such as `ColumnLayout`, `RowLayout`, if you set both `Layout.preferredWidth` AND `Layout.fillWidth: true` it will evenly distribute your children and fill the space accordingly. Similarly for `Layout.preferredHeight` and `Laoyut.fillHeight: true`. By mixing `ColumnLayout` and `RowLayout` we can achieve something similar to what you've requested, i.e.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: page
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        RowLayout {
            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 80
                Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "green"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 40
                Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "blue"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                Layout.preferredHeight: 40
            }
        }
        RowLayout {
            Rectangle { color: "cyan"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                Layout.preferredHeight: 50
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "magenta"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 20
                Layout.preferredHeight: 20
            }
            Rectangle {
                color: "cyan"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                Layout.preferredHeight: 50
            }
        }
        RowLayout {
            Rectangle {
                color: "magenta"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 20
                Layout.preferredHeight: 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAHNnic3ZTNCsIwDMfve4riA4iKguzqxYMH9eK5dnErds3IUkRk7+4+VHDidAgOzalJ/k36I6E6TpBYrHjltNp7+s7tz9AyoUnr8YU8ouPUW8oQxMkTuenAF0nuls4MjYttpbrkC5NWRUhpf6eNKdQElm/JNR4eLpRxUCxtaKAWL0yhQfJFjyDoPSSramWzjQ448gWTgybZHHQYcbMuIdgB5Q0vNaeDl8pr2eHgXpu15gwJwHZFOv4m6dY46Aq0/vom0vEz0KzNYt+w1VF2Nt822JNP5xvnX4Vl2RXr6H3U0aeoPz/TVqv8zxOvTpmXnQFFSNp9)

[EDIT]

I had a go at mocking something that may help as a starting point to what you seem to be asking for. I did use `GridLayout` but I also use a `Repeater` and a `ListModel` to spawn and manipulate the delegates. As you drag/drop the delegates, we can update the `ListModel` forcing the components to rearrange. Although I haven't shown it, rowSpan/columnSpan,preferredWidth/preferredHeight are also manipulatable by updating the

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    GridView {
        id: gridView
        width: 600
        height: 500
        model: 30
        cellWidth: 100
        cellHeight: 100
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "black"
        }
    }
    GridLayout {
        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0

        Repeater {
            model: listModel
            delegate: MyGridDelegate { }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        Component.onCompleted: {
            for (let [col,ro,co,rs,cs,w,h] of [
                [ "red", 1, 1, 1, 1, 100, 100 ],
                [ "green", 1, 2, 2, 1, 200, 200 ]
            ] ) {
                append({col,ro,co,rs,cs,w,h});
            }
        }
    }
}

// MyGridDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Item {
    id: item
    Layout.row: ro
    Layout.column: co
    Layout.rowSpan: rs
    Layout.columnSpan: cs
    Layout.preferredWidth: w
    Layout.preferredHeight: h
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: col
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
            onReleased: {
                co = Math.floor(rect.x / 100)
                ro = Math.floor(rect.y / 100)
                rect.x = 0;
                rect.y = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: What if I want to be able to resize the rectangles inside the layout in runtime? That's the reason why I can't use Columns and Rows, you can't change the height of an element that is inside a RowLayout, as it will change the height of all elements inside that row. I found the exact Layout I need here: [link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Fluid-Drag-and-Drop-Grid-Layout-with-jQuery-gridstack-js/) Do you think it's replicatable in QML at all?

Comment: That's a cool demo. The closest component that Qt has to behaving like that is the Flow control, but, it doesn't behave exactly like that.

Comment: The problem with using Flow is that it doesn't have the indexAt() method so I can't implement the Drag & Drop functionality like I did using the GridView.. It'd be nice if I could just get the ListModel index of hovered item from Flow.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803473/qml-gridlayout-row-and-column-span-understanding

Comment: It actually does help but the logic behind dynamic element resizing and repositioning is a bit too much for me to handle at the time being.

Comment: Re: changing the height of the element, you can set Layout.preferredWidth / Layout.preferredHeight.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use stacked splitters?

```
SplitView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: Qt.Vertical

    SplitView {
        SplitView.preferredHeight: 200

        Rectangle {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 100
            color: "#00FF00"
        }

        Rectangle {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 400
            color: "#00EE00"
        }

        Rectangle {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 200
            color: "#00DD00"
        }
    }

    SplitView {
        SplitView.preferredHeight: 200

        Rectangle {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 400
            color: "#001100"
        }

        Rectangle {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 100
            color: "#002200"
        }

        Rectangle {
            SplitView.preferredWidth: 200
            color: "#003300"
        }
    }
}
```